# npm Cannot find module 'minimatch'

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I update my `Node.js` to 5.5.0.
But it does not work when i use npm.

It reports error:
`Cannot find module 'minimatch'`.

But `Node.js` version 4.2 is ok on my mac.

Answer (score 9):

Remove this folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules`

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules
```

Comment: Worked in my situation, going backward from node 7.4/npm 4 to node 4/npm 2.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I updated my node through the binary but also had a previous version installed through homebrew .
The way I resolved this was, uninstalling node and npm completely and reinstalling using the binary found on their website .

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm
sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
sudo rm /opt/local/bin/node
sudo rm /opt/local/include/node
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules
brew unlink nodejs
```

and reinstall .

Comment: Thank you. I did these commands and reinstall nodejs, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into probably the same exact problem as you.

I went from 4.2.3 LTS to 5.9, and all npm functionality ceased, always generating that error.

I had to do the following:

1. Uninstall Node
2. Save anything in your node installation folder that you may want to keep
3. Completely delete the node installation
4. Re-install 5.9

Everything was tip-top after that. I purged the folder after I noticed that there was the old 4.2.3 installer in the `Installer` directory. I didn't know what the ramifications of that were, but better safe than sorry.